# Star Pattern Recursion Python

Tags: python, recursion

I am to write a recursive function **printPattern()** that will output a pattern in stars. the first argument is always a power of 2 and is the max number of stars appearing in the middle row.  The second argument (which defaults to 0) is the number of spaces to put before each patterns rows of stars.

an example of the output is:

```
>>> printPattern(8,0)
*
**
 *
****
  *
  **
   *
********
    *
    **
     *
    ****
      *
      **
       *
```

i have this code from a previous problem that is similar to what this is asking.

```
def patt(n,s=0):
    if n==1:
        print('*')
    else:
        patt(n-1)
        print('*'*n)
        patt(n-1)
```

im not really sure how to change it so that it only prints out powers of 2.

Comment: so, what do you want to have?

Comment: i want to use the code that i mentioned above to do what the function printPattern() outputs.  the function patt() outputs a similar star pattern but what i want it to do is only output stars if they are a power of 2

Comment: Instead of calling `patt(n-1)`, call `patt(n//2)`

Comment: @OkiErieRinaldi He has given what he wants.

Comment: Also you need to remove check for n == 1 as your first digit will always be even.

Comment: @khrm: He says it will always be a power of 2, not a multiple of 2. 1 is `2**0`.

Comment: @Blckknght  Thanks for correcting me. Even then that check is not necessary.

Comment: @khrm: It is necessary. It's the base case of the recursion. If you didn't include it (or some other similar check), the recursion would continue forever.

Comment: @Blckknght Did you check my solution? I have added only 0 check.

Comment: @khrm: That's what I meant by "some similar check". I think checking for `1` as the base case is nicer, since you can avoid the two extra recursive calls (at the cost of two very easy to understand lines of code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of substracting one, divide by two.

```
def patt(n,s=0):
    if n==1:
        print(' '*s,'*', sep='')
    else:
        patt(n//2, s)
        print(' '*s, '*'*n, sep='')
        patt(n//2, s + n//2)
```

For the spaces, we start with no indentation, and add an indentation of half the current number for the second recursion. This way the pattern you showed in your desired output will emerge.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
def patt(n,s=0):
    if(n>0):
        patt(n//2,s)
        print(" "*s + "*"*n)
        patt(n//2,s+n//2)
```